# Intuitive Explanation for Effective Secrecy

Tags: information-theory

Effective Secrecy is defined by

$D(P_{MZ^n} || P_M Q_{Z^n}) \leq \delta_n$, for some abitary pdf $Q_{Z^n}$.

In the paper "Effective Secrecy: Reliability, Confusion and Stealth" it is written like

$D(P_{MZ^n} || P_M Q_{Z^n}) = \underbrace{I(M;Z^n)}_{\text{Non-Confusion}} + \underbrace{D(P_{Z^n} || Q_{Z^n})}_{\text{Non-Setath}}$

there $I(M;Z^n)$ is the "non-confusion" and $D(P_{Z^n} || Q_{Z^n})$ is the measure of "non-stealth" part and $Q_{Z^n}$ is the distribution that the eavesdropper expects to observe then the source is not comunicating useful messages.

The setup looks like this

```
M -> Encoder -> X^n -> Q^n_YZ|X -> Y^n -> Decoder -> ^M
                                -> I(M;Z^n), D(P_{Z^n}||Q^n_Z)
```

I'm not sure, how to interpret the Non-Stealth part. Has someone a meaning for me? I think, I'm struggeling with the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

Comment: All of your recent questions seem to reduce to issues with the standard interpretations of some information theoretic functionals. My question to you is if you have enough background. Have you, for instance, studied some information theory outside of the context of the paper above? Are you familiar with, say, the channel coding theorem? Sanov's theorem?

Comment: Yeah. I studied a bit information theory. Sometimes I'm struggeling with some interpretation of the formulas. And on stackexchange are very good interpretations! They helped me a lot. That is why I'm asking.
And I know the coding theorem but not the other one. I'm always struggeling with those distance measure. I will try to read something about this.

Comment: My suggestion is to read the chapter on information theory and statistics in Cover and Thomas. It should clarify the role of KL divergence in hypothesis testing. This is relevant to this question ,for instance:  if $D(P\|Q)$ is big, then the eavesdropper can more easily determine if some communication was occuring over the channel or not. If the eavesdropper could not tell this,haracteris then I'd call the communication 'stealthy', and so the $D$ term characterises how 'non-stealthy' this is...